# Who is my Wali?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, sunni, wali

Assalamulikum,
This question has been circling my mind. My parents have been divorced since I was 7 and my mother and I live in the united states while my father lives in a different country. As a female, I know that my father must approve of my marriage however this is difficult for many reasons. He can't come to the united states (he isn't a citizen nor has the ability), I cant go to him and he also most likely won't agree just to be rude to my mom.

So what do I do in that situation?
I don't have a brother and my uncles etc, don't live in the united states. Are they allowed to "give my hand" over face time or something similiar?
If not then what the solution?

Jazakum Allah Khair

Comment: You could check this out: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/227698/marriage-without-the-womans-wali-guardian-and-innovated-divorces-talaaq-bidi

Comment: Your father could appoint a wakil. See also [Who can be wali and in what order](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39553/who-can-be-wali-and-in-what-order), [My fathers rejection of my marriage propsal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/is-my-fathers-irrational-rejection-of-my-marriage-proposal-enough-of-an-excuse) and **[Does the father have to be present during the nikah or is his consent enough?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36986/does-the-father-have-to-be-present-during-the-nikah-or-is-his-consent-enough)**. Note I do assume your father is a Muslim.

Answer (score 1):

Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:

If the wali refused to let a woman marry a man whose religious commitment and character are good, then guardianship passes to the next closest male relative on the father’s side, then the next closest and so on.

If none of these people are Muslim/alive/available, then the local Imam becomes your wali.